# Prepending and animating text loaded via AJAX with jQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

Old hand with Prototype, new to jQuery, and writing a simple app to get a feel for the framework (and because I want to use it).  I've got an HTML fragment that I load via AJAX, and I want to stick this at the top of a `div`, with a slide-in transition animation.

This bit works, and does the prepending bit:

```
// Get the HTML fragment and stick it at the top of the containing div.
$.post("/create_new_thing", function(data) {
    $('#container_div').prepend(data);
});
```

What I'd like to do, and can't figure out, is animate the newly added HTML fragment with a show() effect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have I sufficiently answered your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
$('#div').load('file.html').fadeIn("slow");
```

The load function is better suited to your needs, as it's main purpose is to load HTML from a remote file and inject it into the DOM.

Using the "post" function is better for loading a remote page using a POST request (posting data via a form and returning dynamic data based on your post request).

See below...

```
$.post("file.php", { name: "superuntitled", time: "2am" },
function(data){
  $('#div').fadeIn("slow").append(data);
});
```

jQuery has no support yet for "PUT" requests. So if you really need to use a put request, I can recommend extending the jQuery functionality with a custom function that adds support for "PUT". That said, there are some work arounds! [See here for more details!](http://homework.nwsnet.de/news/9132_put-and-delete-with-jquery%20) ... http://homework.nwsnet.de/news/9132_put-and-delete-with-jquery

Comment: I'll give this a go, but I can see cases where I'll want to do this via a POST request -- I just didn't put any parameters in my example because I want to keep it simple.  Thanks, though!

Comment: @superUntitled: you may read about the put request over at w3c: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6

Comment: jQuery has no support yet for "PUT" requests. So if you really need to use a put request, I can recommend extending the jQuery functionality with a custom function that adds support for "PUT". See here for more details!
http://homework.nwsnet.de/news/9132_put-and-delete-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for adding a new post to the list:

```
success: function(data){
  $("#posts-container").prepend(data).children().first().hide().show('slow');
}
```

This assumes the added element is wrapped in a div and is first in the #posts-container.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this

```
 $.post("yourdocument.php", {parameter:"caucana.com"}, function(data) {
        $('#contiene_resultados').prepend(data);
  });
```